# Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS when pressing button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When i press my button, i got a error of access.
the error : Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0xd0a937db)

**TTest.h**

```
@interface TTtest : NSObject
{
    UIButton *monBouton ;
    UIImage *skin;


}
- (void)initTest :(UIView*)vueDonne;
-(void)test:(id)sender;
```

**TTest.m**

```
    - (void)initTest :(UIView*)vueDonne
    {


            skin = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boutonG" ofType:@"png"]];
            monBouton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            monBouton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 45, 50);
            [monBouton setImage:skin forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [monBouton addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

            [vueDonne addSubview: monBouton];
}
    -(void)test:(id)sender //didn't work because i have the probleme
    {
    NSLog(@"test clicked");
    }
```

**testViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TTtest *test =[[TTtest alloc] init];
    [test initTest:_testView]; //View of my application
}
```

EDIT:
If i add monBouton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
I get a problem of SIGABRT

```
2014-10-26 16:47:22.827 testAsk[2134:a0b] -[CALayerArray test:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa141ea0
2014-10-26 16:47:22.831 testAsk[2134:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray test:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa141ea0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017d6903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172990b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x017294ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ce874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x0022c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x0022c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x003240c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00324484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x003231fd -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 254
    11  UIKit                               0x0026934b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 386
    12  UIKit                               0x0026a184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    13  UIKit                               0x0023de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x0022818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x016c283f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c21cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016df29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0368e9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0368e809 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  testAsk                             0x000027bd main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d75725 start + 0
    25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: by the look of it, I think you need to instantiate the UIButton first `monBouton = [[UIButton alloc] init]`. Give it a try.

Comment: If i add monBouton =[[UIButton alloc] init]
I get a problem of SIGBART, I put the text in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash is that test object is dealloced when it receives the button action.

```
TTtest *test =[[TTtest alloc] init]; //dealloced after viewDidLoad
```

so try to make the test a property and use self.test.

```
self.test =[[TTtest alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yes ! How ? I don't understand why before it's not worked.
Can you explain ?

Comment: So is it working now? because the original test object is a  a local object, which only lives in the viewDidLoad method, out of the scope, it is released to save memory usage, your target action -(void)test:(id)sender is defined in the test object, which no longer exist when you clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you defined the selector "test"

```
-(void)test: (id) sender 
   NSLog(@"test clicked");    
}
```

Comment: Yes i forgot but the methode doesn't work 'cause of "bad access" .